# ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'development' database is not configured

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using MacOS and I'm getting the following error when trying to run rails s or rails routes against a Ruby on Rails repo. I don't know what should be changed.

rails aborted!

ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'development'

database is not configured. Available: ["adapter", "database",

"username", "password", "host", "pool", "timeout", "template"]

/Users/User/myrepo/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'

/Users/User/myrepo/bin/rails:9:in `require'

/Users/User/myrepo/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'

/Users/User/myrepo/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in

`load' bin/rails:3:in` ' Tasks: TOP => routes => environment

This is database.yml

```
  adapter: postgresql
  database: myrepo_development
  username: app_dbuser
  password: password
  host: 127.0.0.1 #myrepo.something-1.rds.amazonaws.com
  pool: 20
  timeout: 5000
  template: template0

staging:
  adapter: "postgresql"
  database: "myrepo"
  encoding: "utf8"
  host: "myrepo-staging.something-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
  username: "app_dbuser"
  password: "password"
  reconnect: true
  port: 5432

production:
  adapter: "postgresql"
  database: "myrepo"
  encoding: "utf8"
  host: "myrepo.something-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
  username: "app_dbuser"
  password: "password"
  reconnect: true
  port: 5432

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: myrepo_test<%= ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] %>
  username: <%= ENV.fetch("DB_USERNAME") { "app_dbuser" }%>
  password: <%= ENV.fetch("DB_PASSWORD") { "password" }%>
  host: <%= ENV.fetch("DB_HOST") { "127.0.0.1" } %>
  pool: 20
  timeout: 5000
  template: template0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the development: line at the top of the file. The yaml looks like it's failing to parse, here's what it should like like.

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: myrepo_development
  username: app_dbuser
  password: cashbox701
  host: 127.0.0.1 #myrepo.something-1.rds.amazonaws.com
  pool: 20
  timeout: 5000
  template: template0

staging:
  adapter: "postgresql"
  database: "myrepo"
  encoding: "utf8"
  host: "myrepo-staging.something-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
  username: "app_dbuser"
  password: "cashbox701"
  reconnect: true
  port: 5432

production:
  adapter: "postgresql"
  database: "myrepo"
  encoding: "utf8"
  host: "myrepo.something-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
  username: "app_dbuser"
  password: "cashbox701"
  reconnect: true
  port: 5432

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: myrepo_test<%= ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] %>
  username: <%= ENV.fetch("DB_USERNAME") { "app_dbuser" }%>
  password: <%= ENV.fetch("DB_PASSWORD") { "cashbox701" }%>
  host: <%= ENV.fetch("DB_HOST") { "127.0.0.1" } %>
  pool: 20
  timeout: 5000
  template: template0
```

Comment: Sorry I can't see where I should change (could you please replace the password value in the answer with "password" if it is convenient? Thanks)

Comment: I understand, I missed a line, there is an indentation error, thank you!

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, but you figured out that the top line was missing :)

Comment: Please don't post only code; it's always better to provide some explanation, too.